# NullReferenceException with Ckeditor 5 and ASP.NET MVC bundle error?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ckeditor5

To isolate any problems so I can reproduce the issue, I started with a brand new project in VS 2017 with the ASP.NET MVC Template (.NET Framework 4.6.1).

I added the latest ckeditor5 to /Scripts/ckeditor5/ckeditor.js

In BundleConfig.cs, I added this:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/ckeditor").Include(
"~/Scripts/ckeditor5/ckeditor.js"));
```

In _layout.cshtml, I have this:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/ckeditor")
```

When I run the application, it gives "System.NullReferenceException" error. It seems Microsoft Ajax parse doesn't like ckeditor5??

> at
>   Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.JSParser.ParseObjectLiteralProperty(Boolean
>   isBindingPattern)\r\n   at
>   Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.JSParser.ParseObjectLiteral(Boolean
>   isBindingPattern)\r\n   at
>   Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.JSParser.ParseLeftHandSideExpression(Boolean
>   isMinus)\r\n   at
>   Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.JSParser.ParseUnaryExpression(Boolean&
>   isLeftHandSideExpr, Boolean isMinus)\r\n   at
>   Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.JSParser.ParseVarDecl(JSToken inToken)\r\n
>   at Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.JSParser.ParseVariableStatement()\r\n   at
>   Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.JSParser.ParseFunctionBody(Block body)\r\n
>   at Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.JSParser.ParseFunction(FunctionType
>   functionType, Context fncCtx)\r\n   at
>   Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.JSParser.ParseLeftHandSideExpression(Boolean
>   isMinus)\r\n   at
>   Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.JSParser.ParseUnaryExpression(Boolean&
>   isLeftHandSideExpr, Boolean isMinus)\r\n   at
>   Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.JSParser.ParseArrayLiteral(Boolean
>   isBindingPattern)\r\n   at

If I forget about Bundle and I hard code the path like this on _Layout.cshtml, it worked:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/ckeditor5/ckeditor.js"></script>
```

Any idea how to make bundle works for ckeditor5?

Comment: The `BundleConfig.cs` file searches the js and css files from his position in the tree structure

Comment: I can confirm the issue, I have reproduced it. The source of the exception is "WebGrease".

Comment: You are right, I saw that in debugger too, module = WebGrease.dll.  This was written by Microsoft and maybe it is not catching up with the latest web technology?  Latest version V1.6.0 was done 2014. Hmmm... it is not compatible with ckeditor 5 in UMD format?  I am not really expert in Javascript, correct me if I am wrong.   Maybe .NET Core 2.2 bundle will work? arrrgg.. but we have to support old MVC project.

Comment: Does it behave the same in debug and release builds?

Answer (score 2):

This issue most probably has to do with the ScriptBundle trying to Minify a file which was already minified. Which in the case of the Ckeditor5 breaks.

The fix was to add .min to the file extension before the .js.

This fixed the issue for me.

Comment: I've a similar issue and I tried this approach, it didn't work. I had to `System.Web.Optimization.BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false;` at the start of `protected void Application_Start()` function in Globel.asax file to disable minification and bundling altogether

Answer (score 1):

You don’t have to use the extension file in the name of ScriptBundle.

Not like this:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                      "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"));
```

Do it like this:

On BundleConfig.cs:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                      "~/Scripts/bootstrap"));
```

---

On file.cshtml:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
```

I found this on this page: https://www.it-swarm-es.com/es/asp.net-mvc/mvc-bundling-no-se-pudo-cargar-el-recurso/1040501977/

Answer (score 0):

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include("~/Scripts/bootstrap"));
```

After using this Top bar Disappeared from Homepage like bootstrap does not working properly

Comment: This does not look like an answer.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31434569)